The "StandardGaussian" bandwidth selection method in the SmoothKernelDistribution function
I have a list of points which follow the Gaussian distribution:
mean = {0.95, 0.5};
sigma = 0.00125;
GaussianBlob = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[mean, {sigma, sigma}, 0],500000];

Then, I use SmoothKernelDistribution to construct a smooth kernel distribution. For the optimal bandwidth, I test "Silverman" and "StandardGaussian". They returned two different bandwidth values:
cXYTDistributionsSilverman = 
SmoothKernelDistribution[GaussianBlob, "Silverman", 
   MaxMixtureKernels -> All, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

bandwidthSilverman = cXYTDistributionsSilverman["Bandwidth"]
{0.000155853, 0.000155889}

cXYTDistributionsGaussian = 
SmoothKernelDistribution[GaussianBlob, "StandardGaussian", 
   MaxMixtureKernels -> All, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];

bandwidthGaussian = cXYTDistributionsGaussian["Bandwidth"]
{0.000183426, 0.000183468}

I can use the answer at The default bandwidth of the SmoothKernelDistribution function, which was provided by @J.M for higher dimensions calculation to get the same result. However, it is still worth noting that after the sample size reaches 100,000, Mathematica will use the constant bandwidth value. This issue is discussed at About Silverman's bandwidth selection in SmoothKernelDistribution.
If I choose a specific contour (0.001) to visualize which bandwidth method provides a better solution. It seems "StandardGaussian" (green) generated a more smooth curve than "Silverman" (blue). The red circle is the exact contour calculated by the Gaussian function.

My questions are: How does Mathematica calculate "StandardGaussian" bandwidth, and is there any other optimal bandwidth calculation for this specific case?
Many thanks!

Please give your complete code as it makes no sense that cXYTDistributions["Bandwidth"] executed twice would give two different results.

Sorry @JimB , I just re-edited my code.

One hint towards a solution is that the ratio of the Standard Gaussian to the Sliverman bandwidths is 1.17692.  And the ratio of the two multiplicative constants in the commonly accepted formulas is 1.05922/0.9 = 1.17691.  So the Standard Gaussian uses a multiplicative factor of 1.06 and the Silverman uses 0.9 (which isn't surprising).  Now you'd just need to figure out what common function of the sample size is used on both.

Thanks @JimB ! I think I found the solution.

@JimB But one thing I'm not sure is why Mathematica will limit the sample size to 100,000. My 500,000 test case yielded the same bandwidth result when I used 100,000 points.
